# Regex for IBAN allowing for white spaces AND checking for exact length

Tags: regex, whitespace, iban

I need to check an input field for a German IBAN. The user should be allowed to leave in white spaces *and* input should be validated to have a starting `DE` and then exact 20 characters numbers and letters.

Without the white space allowance, I tried

```
^[DE]{2}([0-9a-zA-Z]{20})$
```

but I cannot find where and how I can add "white spaces anywhere allowed.

This should be simple, but I simply cannot find a solution.

Thanks for help!

Comment: What language are you using? Is removing all whitespaces from the string a suitable solution? Also, FYI, `[DE]{2}` matches `DD` or `ED`: see http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: as I'm saying in my answer, you're not using the right tool for the task. You *should not* check something as important as an IBAN against a format, but check the validity of the whole code by calculating the checksum, which is, agorithmically, as complex as a regex check.

Comment: Tanks a lot! we do validate the correct IBAN format properly in the backend, but want to guide the user frontend-wise already too.

Comment: do not tend to just guide, just validate it. To repeat myself: a checksum calcul is faster, lighter and easier to do than a regex, and it's the best way to validate an IBAN input!

Answer (score 32):

Here is a list of IBANs from 70 Countries. I generated it with a python script i wrote based on this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number

```
AL[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){2}([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){4}\s?
AD[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){2}([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){3}\s?
AT[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){4}\s?
AZ[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{4}\s?){5}\s?
BH[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z]{4}\s?){1}([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){3}([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})\s?
BY[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{4}\s?){5}\s?
BE[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){3}\s?
BA[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){4}\s?
BR[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){5}([0-9]{3})([a-zA-Z]{1}\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9]{1})\s?
BG[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{2})([a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){1}([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})\s?
CR[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){4}([0-9]{2})\s?
HR[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){4}([0-9]{1})\s?
CY[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){2}([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){4}\s?
CZ[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){5}\s?
DK[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){3}([0-9]{2})\s?
DO[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{4}\s?){5}\s?
TL[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){4}([0-9]{3})\s?
EE[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){4}\s?
FO[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){3}([0-9]{2})\s?
FI[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){3}([0-9]{2})\s?
FR[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){2}([0-9]{2})([a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){2}([a-zA-Z0-9]{1})([0-9]{2})\s?
GE[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}\s?)([0-9]{4}\s?){3}([0-9]{2})\s?
DE[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){4}([0-9]{2})\s?
GI[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z]{4}\s?){1}([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){3}([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})\s?
GR[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{3})([a-zA-Z0-9]{1}\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){3}([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})\s?
GL[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){3}([0-9]{2})\s?
GT[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){1}([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){5}\s?
HU[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){6}\s?
IS[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){5}([0-9]{2})\s?
IE[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{4}\s?){3}([0-9]{2})\s?
IL[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){4}([0-9]{3})\s?
IT[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z]{1})([0-9]{3}\s?)([0-9]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{3})([a-zA-Z0-9]{1}\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){2}([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})\s?
JO[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{4}\s?){5}([0-9]{2})\s?
KZ[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){3}([0-9]{1})([a-zA-Z0-9]{3}\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){2}([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})\s?
XK[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{4}\s?){2}([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}\s?)\s?
KW[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z]{4}\s?){1}([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){5}([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})\s?
LV[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z]{4}\s?){1}([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){3}([a-zA-Z0-9]{1})\s?
LB[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){1}([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){5}\s?
LI[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{1})([a-zA-Z0-9]{3}\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){2}([a-zA-Z0-9]{1})\s?
LT[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){4}\s?
LU[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{3})([a-zA-Z0-9]{1}\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){3}\s?
MK[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{3})([a-zA-Z0-9]{1}\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){2}([a-zA-Z0-9]{1})([0-9]{2})\s?
MT[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{1})([a-zA-Z0-9]{3}\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){3}([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})\s?
MR[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){5}([0-9]{3})\s?
MU[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{4}\s?){4}([0-9]{3})([a-zA-Z]{1}\s?)([a-zA-Z]{2})\s?
MC[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){2}([0-9]{2})([a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){2}([a-zA-Z0-9]{1})([0-9]{2})\s?
MD[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})([a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){4}\s?
ME[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){4}([0-9]{2})\s?
NL[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{4}\s?){2}([0-9]{2})\s?
NO[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){2}([0-9]{3})\s?
PK[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{4}\s?){4}\s?
PS[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{4}\s?){5}([0-9]{1})\s?
PL[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){6}\s?
PT[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){5}([0-9]{1})\s?
QA[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z]{4}\s?){1}([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){5}([a-zA-Z0-9]{1})\s?
RO[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z]{4}\s?){1}([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){4}\s?
SM[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z]{1})([0-9]{3}\s?)([0-9]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{3})([a-zA-Z0-9]{1}\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){2}([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})\s?
SA[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{2})([a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){4}\s?
RS[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){4}([0-9]{2})\s?
SK[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){5}\s?
SI[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){3}([0-9]{3})\s?
ES[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){5}\s?
SE[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){5}\s?
CH[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{1})([a-zA-Z0-9]{3}\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){2}([a-zA-Z0-9]{1})\s?
TN[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){5}\s?
TR[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{1})([a-zA-Z0-9]{3}\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){3}([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})\s?
AE[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{3})([0-9]{1}\s?)([0-9]{4}\s?){3}([0-9]{3})\s?
GB[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{4}\s?){3}([0-9]{2})\s?
VA[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{3})([0-9]{1}\s?)([0-9]{4}\s?){3}([0-9]{2})\s?
VG[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{4}\s?){4}\s?
```

Comment: Don't know why the downvotes. This list is at least incredibly helpful. These seem correct. And the German regex is in your answer.

Comment: GB seems to be wrong!
`GB82 WEST 1234 5698 7654 322` is considered valid, but it's 1 char too long!

Answer (score 31):

Because you should use the right tool for the right task: **you should not rely on regexps** to validate IBAN numbers, but instead use the IBAN checksum algorithm to check the whole code is actually correct, making any regexp superfluous and redundant. *i.e.*: remove all spaces, rearrange the code, convert to integers, and compute remainder, [here it's best explained](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number#Algorithms).

Though, there am I trying to answer your question, for the fun of it:

what about:

```
^DE([0-9a-zA-Z]\s?){20}$
```

which only difference is allowing a whitespace (or not) after each occurence of a alphanumeric character.

[here](https://www.debuggex.com/r/4-lQJ8UWBzNTV0-q) is the visualization:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

edit: for the OP's information, the only difference is that this regexp, from @ulugbex-umirov: `(?:\s*[0-9a-zA-Z]\s*)` does a lookahead check to see if there's a space between the iso country code and the checksum (which only made of numerical digits), which I do not support on purpose.

And actually to support a correct IBAN syntax, which is formed of groups of 4 characters, as the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number#Practicalities) says:

```
^DE\d{2}\s?([0-9a-zA-Z]{4}\s?){4}[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[example](https://www.debuggex.com/r/gVeeDYaTl7oSE91k)

If your UI is in Javascript, you can use [that](https://github.com/arhs/iban.js) library for doing IBAN validation:

```
<script src="iban.js"></script>
<script>
    // the API is now accessible from the window.IBAN global object
    IBAN.isValid('hello world'); // false
    IBAN.isValid('BE68539007547034'); // true
</script>
```

so you *know* this is a valid IBAN, and can validate it before the data is ever even sent to the backend. Simpler, lighter and more elegant… Why do something else?

Comment: Good point about not relying on regexs to validate an IBAN, but I think a regex can be used in the frontend to catch any obvious mistakes and guide the user. I would do the more serious IBAN validation in the backend.

Comment: thanks a ton for you quick and very helpful answer! we do validate in the backend as well. the regex is additional, for user guidance

Comment: nope, you're wrong, the checksum validation is really light, if not lighter than a regex check! And it would enable to help the user detect any *real* error, and not simply format errors, the format errors being often a problem. And also, you may support *any* checksum, and not only the german ones… and I've been customer to many german sites that only accept payments from german-speaking countries, whereas I'm not living in one of those… We're in Europe, we got SEPA and IBANs! :-)

Comment: btw, if your UI is in javascript, there's a bunch of JS libraries: [here](http://toms-cafe.de/iban/iban.html), [there](https://gist.github.com/krypton/5540925) or [there](https://github.com/arhs/iban.js) that impements the checksum calculation.

Comment: I came across this question sepcifically because I had to solve a bug where an old-style, national account number had by pure chance matched the checksum algorithm and thus passed as an IBAN. So I decided to add a regex check. Best solution: Do both.

Comment: @fbitterlich did you post detailed information about this bug anywhere? I don't see it as an issue on the arhs/iban.js github page.

Comment: @klyonrad To clarify: the bug I mentioned was in my own (non-published) code. Adding a dual check (checksum and regex) allows me to more reliably tell IBAN and old-style account numbers apart.

Comment: @zmo: This answer makes me want to be able to upvote twice :-)

Comment: Thank you, glad it helped :-)

Comment: There is even a [python library](https://github.com/mdomke/schwifty) for this.

Answer (score 6):

Original:

```
^[DE]{2}([0-9a-zA-Z]{20})$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/N1_SLzMajIhWDmwb)

Modified:

```
^DE(?:\s*[0-9a-zA-Z]\s*){20}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/CjfeGvjwTNXsykQ1)

Answer (score 4):

This is the correct regex to match DE IBAN account numbers:

```
DE\d{2}[ ]\d{4}[ ]\d{4}[ ]\d{4}[ ]\d{4}[ ]\d{2}|DE\d{20}

Pass:   DE89 3704 0044 0532 0130 00|||DE89370400440532013000
Fail:   DE89-3704-0044-0532-0130-00
```

Answer (score 3):

Most simple solution I can think of:

```
^DE(\s*[[:alnum:]]){20}\s*$
```

In particular, your initial `[DE]{2}` is wrong, as it allows 'DD', 'EE', 'ED' as well as the intended 'DE'.

Answer (score 1):

To allow any amount of spaces anywhere:

```
^ *D *E( *[A-Za-z0-9]){20} *$
```

As you want to allow lower letters, also `DE` might be lower?

```
^ *[Dd] *[Ee]( *[A-Za-z0-9]){20} *$
```

- `^` matches the start of the string
- `$` end anchor
- in between each characters there are optional spaces `*`
- `[`[character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)`]` defines a set/range of characters

To allow at most one space in between each characters, replace the [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*` (any amount of) with `?` (0 or 1). If supported, `\s` [shorthand](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) can be used to match `[ \t\r\n\f]` instead of space only.

[Test on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/bO2dW7), also see the [SO regex FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075)

Answer (score 0):

Using Google Apps Script, I pasted [Laurent's code](https://github.com/arhs/iban.js/blob/master/iban.js) from [github](https://github.com/arhs/iban.js) into a [script](https://script.google.com/d/1ivvUYrNvaLL625FP1W4nCIfOif7shxYgASmvhoeMpHDMni1K5YQDewpV/edit?usp=sharing) and added the following code to test.

```
// Use the Apps Script IDE's "Run" menu to execute this code.
// Then look at the View > Logs menu to see execution results.

function myFunction() {
//https://github.com/arhs/iban.js/blob/master/README.md
// var IBAN = require('iban');
var t1 = IBAN.isValid('hello world'); // false
var t2 = IBAN.isValid('BE68539007547034'); // true
var t3 = IBAN.isValid('BE68 5390 0754 7034'); // true

Logger.log("Test 1 = %s", t1);
Logger.log("Test 2 = %s", t2);
Logger.log("Test 3 = %s", t3);
}
```

The only thing needed to run the example code was commenting out the `require('iban')` line:
    // var IBAN = require('iban');
Finally, instead of using client handlers to attempt a RegEx validation of IBAN input, I use a a server handler to do the validation.