# Custom email regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I trying to create custom email regexp

[first]@[second].[third]

- Allowed signs are numbers, letters and some special characters (I have done it)
- One @
- First+second to be from 1 to 20 characters long.
- Email can't start or end with dot. Two or more dots next to each other are also not 
  allowed.
- Third string to be 2 or 3 characters long.

This is what I have so far:

```
^(?!\.)(?=[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]).{2,21}(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9].{2,3})$
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work as I expected. Thanks for any tips.

For instance I can add multiple dots next to each other:
test...s@fm.com

Comment: Why do you say it does not work? What inputs did you try and what was the output?

Comment: well, multiple dots is a valid email value, what's the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Answer (score 1):

Never ever write a regex to check for e-mails. You'll never make it right. As an example you say:

> *Allowed signs are numbers, letters and some special characters (I have done it)*

which is terribly wrong, because you're then not including unicode characters like å or ţ which are valid. I'm also pretty sure you don't know that `@` is a valid value within the first part of an e-mail.

> *Third string to be 2 or 3 characters long.*

and what about matching the following tlds: `.info`, `.ninja`, `.website` or `.space`?

So please, don't.

for reference:

- https://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23471591/regex-for-iban-allowing-for-white-spaces-and-checking-for-exact-length/23471740#23471740
- http://thedailywtf.com/articles/how-to-validate-a-url

Comment: That's why I've said in title "Custom email". It doesn't have to comply with general standards. Thanks for answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Following regex might help you.

```
^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,3}))$
```

Please read answer posted by @zmo too.

Comment: a case for what I said: this regex does not match `foo@example.website` or the multiple dot thing `foo.....bar@example.com` which both are perfectly valid email addresses.